# Save data to session state and keep synchronized with Froms Auth Session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, session-state

I want to save some data to the session state. I need to save this data off when a user first logs in via forms authentication. I need this session state variable to have the same lifetime as the forms authentication ticket expiration. Is there some way to ensure that these two stay synchronized?

Comment: You can do that only if you both check them all the time. For example, you check if (SessionData exist && UserIsLogedOn) every time you need to read the session data.

Comment: Thanks. The data I want to secure is the users password (existing web service so I don't have a choice) and I thought session state would be safer then in the form authentication ticket. You can't think of a better place to store it so I don't have these synchronize issues can you?

Comment: The session state is not safer ! the cookie of session state can be stolen and get the session.

Comment: But they can't get the actually data. Its only server side.

Comment: If they steal the cookie, then they put it on a web page, and then read what you send on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some way to ensure that these two stay synchronized?

Both have a timeout value in web.config that you can set to the same value. Now this being said here's where your problems might start. A forms authentication cookie might have a sliding expiration setup whereas a session not. So make sure you disable this sliding expiration for the authentication cookie if you want the two timeout values to match. And that's just the beginning. For the session you can choose where to store it: Off, InProc, StateServer, SqlServer.

When you use Off (personally what I use) ASP.NET session is disabled and you basically don't have any session.

When you set it to InProc (which is the default value) the session is stored in memory. Except that IIS could decide to recycle the AppDomain under different circumstances: a period of inactivity, certain CPU/memory threshold is reached, ... This basically means that if the session is stored in memory and the AppDomain is unloaded by the web server you loose everything stored in this session whereas, obviously, the authentication cookie continues to be valid.

StateServer and SQLServer are 2 different modes of out of process session storage where the information is no longer stored in the memory of the web server and can survive AppDomain being recycled.

So basically to sum up it is very difficult to synchronize in a reliable manner the ASP.NET session lifecycle and the ASP.NET forms authentication cookie lifecycle. I solve this problem by not using ASP.NET session at all.